# Biztalk Server 2010 application deployment with partial bindings

Tags: binding, biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-deployment

I have an application on Biztalk Server 2010 with three Receive port and three send ports. I deploy this application on some other machine by Exporting and Importing .MSI file process. I make some changes in a map and in only one receive port bindings. Now i want to deploy these changes on the other machine. Is there a way that while exporting the .MSI file, only the changed bindings are made the part of .MSI file and not the unchanged ones.

Answer (score 2):

1. Export the full bindings as file.
2. Edit the bindings file and Remove all the other ports and information that hasn't changed. e.g. remove everything between ModuleRefCollection and /ModuleRefCollection and leave the changed port in the SendPortCollection or ReceivePortCollection (whichever is applicable).
3. Add the edited file as a resource to the application
4. Export the MSI and include the binding file that you added.

Comment: Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Not that I know off.  The other approach is to get a full copy of the binding from the target environment and load it in your development environment and edit it so that the configuration is correct, then to export that and include it as a resource.   Note: If you have any passwords on any of the ports, you will have to re-enter those in the target environment.